# Kendo listview item/element access

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, listviewitem

I have the following template with 'Name' populated though PHP/mysql. Note that I have a remove button(a tag).

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="usrList">
        <strong style="position:relative;top:5px;left:5px">${Name}</strong>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" id="delete_user" onClick="delusr()" style="float:right;font-size:85%;padding:3px;"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Remove</a>
    </div> 
</script>
```

When I click the remove button I want to get the 'Name' (strong tag) next to it. Say inside a js function likes this (doesn't work ofcourse)

```
function delusr(e){
   var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
   var data = listView.dataSource.view();
   alert(data[$(e).index()].Name);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `this` as argument of `delusr`:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="usrList">
        <strong style="position:relative;top:5px;left:5px">${Name}</strong>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" id="delete_user" onClick="delusr(this)" style="float:right;font-size:85%;padding:3px;"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Remove</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

and the define the function `delusr` as:

```
function delusr(elem) {
    var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    var item = $(elem).closest("[role='option']");
    var data = listView.dataSource.getByUid(item.data("uid"));
    alert(data.Name);
}
```

What I do is find the `uid` of the element of the list that has been clicked and then get the data using `getByUid` for that item.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai! Can you explain the line with closest function?

Comment: Look for the closest ancestor of the `$(elem)` node that has an attribute named `role` with a value `'option'`